# Inequality for integral of complex valued functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory

assume that $f$ is a complex-valued function acting on some probability space $(X,m)$ and $g$ a non-negative function defined on a same space such that
$$ \lvert \int_A f \, dm \rvert  \le \int_A g \, dm $$,
for every measurable set $A$. Can we conclude that
$$ \lvert f\rvert \le g$$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I know how to prove this for real-valued $f$.